# Wood rot fix for siding and framing base?

Tags: repair, wood, waterproofing, siding, rot

Wood rot fix for siding and frame base?

Some water is seeping into my garage when it rains. Called a concrete guy because I thought patio was too sloped, but he said sloping was by design and he suggested the real issue is the siding has wood rot and it’s letting water damage the wood frame above the concrete slab and water is coming in that way. He suggested flex foam to seal - seems easy and cheap but will it be sufficient? Any other recommendations? My fear is worst case scenario requires tearing out the wood frame and rebuild. The ultimate goal is to add a small room to part of the garage so don’t want water seeping into new room. [image]

Comment: Is the inside an open wall, or is it closed in with drywall or something? If it's open, a pic from there might be useful.

Comment: I would not use any kind of expanding foam. They expand too much, collect dirt and would create a bubbly, barf effect on the outside of your house! There are very good siding caulks made by OSI Quad series, available at the big boxes.   A picture of the interior wall, if open, would be helpful.